# Angular Bootstrap UI carousel and Angular 1.3.15

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've been looking for a solution for this issue seems like a lot of people is asking for support to angular 1.3 in angular bootstrap seems like the issue is still open in [github](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2830#issuecomment-67828920).

well my issue is when I use the carousel I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:199:317

the carousel was working fine in angular 1.2

the code is just a standard carousel

```
<carousel interval="carouselInterval" id="sliderControl">
            <slide>
                <div class="grid1170 stage">
                    <h2>Step 1</h2>
                    <p>some text</p>
                </div>
            </slide>
            <slide>
                <div class="grid1170 stage">
                    <h2>step2</h2>
                    <p>
                        some text
                    </p>
                </div>
            </slide>
            <slide>
                <div class="grid1170 stage">
                    <h2>step3</h2>
                    <p>
                     some text
                    </p>
                </div>
            </slide>
        </carousel>
```

I guess it has some relation with ng-animate since the error happens on every slide transition.

any ideas?

Comment: Yeah basically there is a problem with the carousel and ngAnimate like you guessed... you can use a directive to disable ngAnimate doing anything to the carousel directive or it's children, that works but I personally use the angular-slick library for doing the carousels because it's touch friendly and doesn't slam the CPU during animation as badly.

Comment: interesting let me check, thanks for the heads up

Comment: [This](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/431b9c76b05f2bab693e05b60d3c50b51a1459ee) commit should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
For carousel to work roll back to angular UI 0.12.1 
Carousel still has some issues..All the other directives work decently so far.
Currently looking at angular-slick for carousels...


you need /*!
 * Bootstrap v3.1.1 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

/**
 * @license AngularJS v1.4.3
 * (c) 2010-2015 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
 * License: MIT
 */
Taken from app.js 
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngTouch'

Taken from Index.html
 <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Comment: thanks, I noticed that I have to roll back, in my case isn't an option